# Exposed filter with Ajax breaks form

Tags: views, commerce, ajax

I have views - catalog with products and I have exposed filter attached (for filtering by brands). All is ok when you don't use this filter however, you can add product to cart). When I use filter and Ajax loads products for certain brand, however, add to cart form breaks.

The example you can see here http://zoo812.ru/catalog/79

What can be done about it? I'm using Commerce.

Comment: I analyzed code and I see, that add to cart form ids change when products are loaded with Ajax. However, seems that system awaits the same ids.

Comment: though form_id and form_token are the same